# xml.etree.ElementTree append parent tag to child tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse a xml string, find a specific tag, and wrap the child tag by appending a parent tag .

My XML:

```xml
<a>
      <b>text1</b>
      <c>text2</c>

</a>
```

Desired XML:

```xml
<a>
      <b>text1</b>
      <new_parent_tag_added>
         <c>text2</c>
      </new_parent_tag_added>
</a>
```

Current code:

```
document_root = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring( XML_STRING))
root = document_root.find('a')
b = etree.SubElement(root, 'new_parent_tag_added')
c = etree.SubElement(b, 'c')
```

In above code, how can I retain the value of my existing tag `<c>` so that it matches with my desired xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the builtin ElementTree module, you can do (thank you @mzjn):

```py
c = root.find('c')
etree.SubElement(root, 'new_parent_tag_added').append(c)
root.remove(c)
```

With [lxml.etree](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) it's a bit shorter:

```py
etree.SubElement(root, 'new_parent_tag_added').append(root.find('c'))
```

Either way, it's good to remember nodes behave like lists, so you can append things.

Comment: This code works with lxml. With ElementTree, it results in two `c` elements in the output. An explicit `root.remove(c)` is needed.

Comment: @mzjn is there any way i can do using ```from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree```?

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the "original" `c` element.

Comment: By the way, refer to the builtin module as "ElementTree". "xml" is just the top-level package and it contains several XML-related submodules: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html.

Comment: @mzjn do you mind to share some example which achieve my above requirement?

Comment: @fsimonjetz , I am facing error here is my example

```from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
document_root = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring( XML_STRING))
root = document_root.find('a')
c = root.find('c')
ET.SubElement(root, 'new_parent_tag_added').append(c)
root.remove(c)```
Here is ERROR
```etree.SubElement(root, 'new_parent_tag_added').append(c)
TypeError: SubElement() argument 1 must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not None```

Comment: @user1591156 Looks like no element 'a' was found? (Btw, I had a typo in my code, replace `ET` with `etree`!) The code works as expected with your example xml string!